# Creates new database when there is no file instead of raising error

Tags: php, error-handling, sqlite, pdo

Im using SQLite and PDO in PHP for the first time.

I wrote simple connect procedure:

```
try 
{
    $link = new PDO("sqlite:".$file);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'SQLite error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I moved my database file, to test error handling and... new database was created.

**I don't want new database, i want error! What should I do?**

Temporarily i wrote `if` with `file_exists()` condition, but maybe there is better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. This behaviour is by design and covers (I guess ;)) 99% of all use-cases, because in a common setup the database is created only once and doesn't just move. This said: `file_exists()` is the way to go :) And it's not bad, so why looking for a better way?

Comment: Im that 1% case, who move databases... My SQLite database is moving container :) Maybe you are right, that `file_exists()` is not so bad... Ill stay with it.

Comment: @Kamil In this case `file_exists()` (or an equivalent) makes even more sense: It's like the difference between a fresh copy and an update. (Maybe my 99% was a little bit too high ;))